# Sort from the lowest to the highest with respective index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data set having fomat like the following:

```
[i] [j] distance_from_point[i]_to_point[k]
1  2  1.51  #distance between point 1 and point 2 is 1.51
1  3  1.42  #distance between point 1 and point 2 is 1.42
1  4  2.44
1  5  1.97
1  6  1.10
1  7  1.10
1  8  2.19
2  1  1.51
2  3  2.42
2  4  1.21
2  5  3.26
2  6  2.11
2  7  2.11
2  8  1.11
3  1  1.42
3  2  2.42
3  4  2.77
3  5  0.97
3  6  2.11
3  7  2.10
3  8  3.39
4  1  2.44
4  2  1.21
4  3  2.77
4  5  3.73
4  6  3.10
4  7  3.13
4  8  2.03
5  1  1.97
5  2  3.26
5  3  0.97
5  4  3.73
5  6  2.37
5  7  2.37
5  8  4.13
6  1  1.10
6  2  2.11
6  3  2.11
6  4  3.10
6  5  2.37
6  7  1.76
6  8  2.46
7  1  1.10
7  2  2.11
7  3  2.10
7  4  3.13
7  5  2.37
7  6  1.76
7  8  2.45
8  1  2.19
8  2  1.11
8  3  3.39
8  4  2.03
8  5  4.13
8  6  2.46
8  7  2.45
```

I would like to sort the distance from the shortest to the longest one with the corresponding index having a format like this:

```
[i]  [k]_correspond_1st_shortest_distance_to[i]  1st_shortest_distance  [l]_correspond_2nd_shortest_distance_to[i]  2nd_shortest_distance  [m]_correspond_3rd_shortest_distance_to[i]  3rd_shortest_distance  [n]_correspond_4th_shortest_distance_to[i]  4th_shortest_distance  ...
```

This seems more complicated than what the sorted() function can do.
Results:

```
1  6  1.10  7  1.10  3  1.42  2  1.51  5  1.97  8  2.19  4  2.44
2  8  1.11  4  1.21  1  1.51  6  2.11  7  2.11  3  2.42  5  3.26
3  5  0.97  1  1.42  7  2.10  6  2.11  2  2.42  4  2.77  8  3.39
...
```

Comment: Can you specify your dataset format (like CSV or something else)?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = """<yourdata>""" 
lines = l.split('\n')  # makes a list one line one elem.

# We load all your data in a dict we use default dict for convenience as he already anitialise an empty list and so we can append wihtout checking if key exist.
dico = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines:
    (start , end, dist) = line.split()
    dico[start].append((end, dist))


# we are going to need this it takes a list of lists and return a list
def flatten(list_):
    """ 
    Flatten a list of lists
    list_:  a list of lists
    return a list
    """
    l = []
    for sublist in list_:
        for elem in sublist:
            l.append(elem)
    return l

# et voilà
list_key = sorted(dico.keys())
for k in list_key:
    v = sorted(dico[k], key=lambda x: x[1])  # we sort on the second elem of the list which is the distance
    # in my example we work with string but if you have int and want to cast back to str for printing you can use this list comprehension [str(x) for x in flatten(v)] this give you a list that you can join.
    print(k, " ".join(flatten(v)))
```

nothing to crazy if you have question don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think "join" connects elements inside list of strings, then flatten(v) should be edited to be str(flatten(v)).